# Can users (non-administrators) log their hours in CiviVolunteer

Tags: civivolunteer

I'm working to setup CiviVolunteer for an organization that wants to track volunteer hours throughout the year. They'd like for individuals to log their own hours. Is this possible yet? I looked in the documentation, though, couldn't tell or not: http://civicrm.github.io/org.civicrm.volunteer/docs/320-manage-volunteer-projects/.

I did allow "CiviVolunteer: log own hours" and "CiviVolunteer: register to volunteer" to "authenticated users".

Please let me know if this is possible and if so, how to set it up so that they can.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not yet, though we'll be pushing this into a release before the end of the year. (Sorry about the misleading "log own hours" permission -- we got a little ahead of ourselves there!)

Comment: Has this been implemented?